# MediaElement not playing audio from stream WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stream, audio-streaming, mediaelement

```
 string url = re["response"][0]["url"].ToString();
 MediaElement mm = new MediaElement();
 mm.Source = new Uri(url,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 mm.AutoPlay = true;
 mm.Volume = 0.7;
 mm.Play();
```

But no changes, the adudio not starts.How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your MediaElement to your VisualTree before playing it, since you're creating it in the codebehind. For example, assuming you have `LayoutRoot` and that your `url` is correct, this should work.

```
string url = re["response"][0]["url"].ToString();
MediaElement mm = new MediaElement();
mm.Source = new Uri(url,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
mm.AutoPlay = true;
mm.Volume = 0.7;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(mm);
mm.Play();
```

Comment: Also remember that when debugging a MediaElement your phone cannot be connected to zune, otherwise it won't play. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for more info on using the Connect tool to use this kind of debugging

Comment: Good point Tom. I've written a blog post showing how to add the WPConnect tool into Visual Studio for quick access: http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/making-it-easier-to-debug-media-in-windows-phone-7-apps/