# WP : MediaElement Is Never Playing

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this app with C# Code but the MP3 just not playing.

```
 music = new MediaElement();

 music.AutoPlay = false;
 music.Source = new Uri("/music/musicNormal.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);
 music.CurrentStateChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(music_CurrentStateChanged);
 music.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(music_MediaOpened);
```

For`currentStateChanged` event I give a MessageBox, but it never triggered.
For `MediaOpened` event I give a line `music.Play()`, but it also never triggered

I have these functions

```
private void changeMusic(bool normal)
    {
        music.Stop();
        if (normal)
            music.Source = new Uri("/music/musicNormal.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);
        else
            music.Source = new Uri("/music/musicFast.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);
    }

private void playMusic()
    {
        if (timeBar.Value <= 10 && music1)
        {
            timeNumber.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            changeMusic(false);
            music2 = true;
            music1 = false;
        }
        else if (timeBar.Value > 10 && music2)
        {
            timeNumber.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            changeMusic(true);
            music1 = true;
            music2 = false;
        }
        if (musicEnabled) music.Play();
    }
```

I have tried :

- Tracking through MediaFailed event, but it is never failed
- Changing the UriKind to Relative and RelativeOrAbsolute
- Give/take away the slash on the beginning of the URI
- Tried to separate those two into 2 mediaElement
- Setting the mp3 to resource, content, embedded resource

What I know :

- The state always "Closed"
- If I specified the URI in XAML, it works. But I don't wanna do that.
- All Function are working properly based on the condition. Just the music won't start.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Answer Found! My bad for not searching in SOF deeper : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018335/mediaelement-not-playing-audio-from-stream-wp7

Before we could modify MediaElement in Code, we need to visualize it in the XAML first.

Can't post answer before 7 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer Found! My bad for not searching in SOF deeper : stackoverflow.com/questions/7018335/… Before we could modify MediaElement in Code, we need to visualize it in the XAML first.